# Сборка программ на Ассемблер под FreeDos

Tags: ассемблер, masm32, компоновщик, dos

Начал читать книгу: *Питер Абель. Ассемблер и программирование для IBM PC*.

В ней говорится, что нужно вставить дискету с ассемблерным пакетом, на которой находятся две версии ассемблера - *Asm.exe* и *Masm.exe*. Также говорится про компоновщик *LINK*.

Использую *VirtualBox* с *FreeDos*. Где взять эти ассемблеры и компоновщик?

Хотел бы использовать синтаксис и действия, которые указаны в книге. Например, необходимо ассемблировать и скомпоновать следующую программу.

```
CODESG SEGMENT PARA 'CODE'
BEGIN  PROC FAR
       ASSUME CS:CODESG,DS:DATASG,SS:STACKG
       PUSH DS
       SUB AX,AX
       PUSH AX
       MOV AX,DATASG
       MOV DS,AX
       RET
BEGIN  ENDP
CODESG ENDS
       END BEGIN
```

Пытался ассемблировать с помощью *JWASM*. Выводит следующие ошибки:

[image: Код программы]

[image: Попытка ассемблирования с помощью _JWASM_]

Comment: скачиваешь установщик и устанавливаешь

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но не могли бы вы сказать более конкретно, где  я могу скачать установщик? Искал на официальном http://www.freedos.org/software/ , но найти _Asm.exe_ или _LINK_ так и не смог.

Comment: по твоей ссылке например: [JWasm is a free MASM-compatible assembler supporting 16, 32 and 64-bit code generation.](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/micro/pc-stuff/freedos/files/distributions/1.2/repos/pkg-html/jwasm.html)

Comment: А еще вот такой например: [free masm](http://service.scs.carleton.ca/sivarama/asm_book_web/free_MASM.html)

Comment: Попытался ассемблировать через _JWasm_, но выдает ошибки. Прикрепил изображения к основному сообщению.

Comment: @Николай, попробуйте у себя в коде DATASEG, STACKSEG заменить на CODESEG.

Comment: Да, изменил все идентификаторы DATASG и STACKSG на CODESG и программа ассемблировалась. Видимо, нужно немного редактировать код примеров. Спасибо :)

Comment: @insolor, может ответом?

Comment: @Grundy, добавил ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробуем собрать исходник с помощью masm32:

```
ml /c test.asm
```

Получаем результат:

```
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: test.asm
test1742.asm(3) : error A2006: undefined symbol : DATASG
test1742.asm(3) : error A2006: undefined symbol : STACKG
test1742.asm(7) : error A2006: undefined symbol : DATASG
```

Т.е. проблема не в JWasm. Причина в том, что в коде указаны имена секций, которых у вас в коде нет. Нужно либо заменить эти имена на имя секции, которая у вас в коде есть (`CODESEG`), либо добавить нужные секции в код:

```
CODESG SEGMENT PARA 'CODE'
BEGIN  PROC FAR
       ASSUME CS:CODESG,DS:DATASG,SS:STACKG
       PUSH DS
       SUB AX,AX
       PUSH AX
       MOV AX,DATASG
       MOV DS,AX
       RET
BEGIN  ENDP
CODESG ENDS

DATASG SEGMENT
DATASG ENDS

STACKG SEGMENT STACK
    db 256 dup (?)
STACKG ENDS

END BEGIN
```

Собираю при помощи masm32 (из Windows):

```
ml /c test.asm
link16 test.obj,test.exe,nul,nul,nul
```

Результат:

```
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: test.asm

Microsoft (R) Segmented Executable Linker  Version 5.60.339 Dec  5 1994
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-1993.  All rights reserved.
```

Под DOSBox полученный исполняемый файл запускается, и успешно завершается, ничего не выводя)